# Ускорить расчет скользящего среднего в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Код ниже считает скользящее среднее для каждой строки на отфильтрованном датафрейме. И все замечательно, но очень медленно. Возможно есть способ ускорить этот расчет? У меня более 200000 строк. Полный код:

```
startdate = pd.to_datetime('2019-06-02')
df['RES1_1Y'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: (df.loc[
        (
            (df.DATE_G < x.DATE_G)
            & (df.DATE_G >= (x.DATE_G + pd.DateOffset(days=-365)))
            & (df.ID1_G == x.ID1_G)
            & (df.ID_C_T == x.ID_C_T)
        ),
        "RES",
    ].mean()) if x.DATE_G > startdate else x.RES1_1Y,
    axis=1,
)
```

Мне предлагали использовать Rolling_mean, на как там задать условия для фильтрации я не знаю. Пример данных:

```
DATE_G     ID1_G ID_C_T RES RES1_1Y
03.06.2019  35802   1   1   
04.06.2019  13592   2   0   
05.06.2019  28267   2   0   
06.06.2019  36327   1   0   
07.06.2019  28267   1   0   
08.06.2019  78317   1   0   
09.06.2019  13101   2   0   
10.06.2019  28267   2   1   0
11.06.2019  46752   2   0   
12.06.2019  36320   1   1   
13.06.2019  28108   2   0   
14.06.2019  72815   1   1   
15.06.2019  31819   1   0   
16.06.2019  28267   2   0   0.5
17.06.2019  14953   1   0   
18.06.2019  23381   1   0   
19.06.2019  29260   1   1   
20.06.2019  35498   1   0   
21.06.2019  28267   2   0   0.333333333
22.06.2019  5058    2   0   
23.06.2019  4003    5   0
```

Comment: Можете словами описать, что именно вы тут фильтруете? Потому что по коду ощущение, что вы пытаетесь сделать что-то странное.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вам нужно найти среднее за год по одинаковым ID1_G и ID_C_T ? Если да, то, кажется, тут можно обойтись просто rolling_mean по предварительно сгруппированным данным.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите, то вам нужно что-то подобное:

```
df['RES1_1Y'] = (df
                 .set_index('DATE_G')
                 .groupby(['ID1_G', 'ID_C_T'])
                 .rolling(window=365, freq='D', min_periods=1)
                 )['RES'].mean()
```

Comment: Спасибо, протестирую